# Bootstrap + CSS: Constrain table height in modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table inside a Bootstrap modal:

```
...modal container...
<div class="modal-body">
                    ...extra code...
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="co-page-orderlist" style="display:none">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th class="selectorBox"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Notes</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I, wanting to keep the table a fixed height, do so in CSS:

```
#co-page-orderlist {
    height: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

However, this is what happens when I have too many rows:

[image]

I want to constrain the height and make that table scrollable. How should I do so?

A workaround that I found is just to constrain the `.modal-body`, which works but doesn't work the way I want to:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use style in div like this :

```
<div class="form-group" id="co-page-orderlist">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered"  style="display:none">
```

Comment: setting display to none removes the table

Answer (score 1):

Remove the css, do this inline css to **modal-body** div like below:

```
 <div class="modal-body" style="height: 500px !important; overflow-y: scroll">
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to modify modal body. It's your table not the modal. Set overflow to scroll:

```
#co-page-orderlist {
    height: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

That should work.